# Issue with Angular 7 trackBy

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am having a weird issue with Angular 7 trackBy. I've got a `ParentComponent` and a `ChildComponent`. I am using `ngfor` in the following way:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let te of entries; let teIndex = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
   <app-entry (teUpdater)="updateEntry($event)" [entry]="te" [entryIndex]="teIndex">
   </app-entry>
 /ng-container>
```

This works fine. I've got a delete button on every child component, which when clicked sends an update to the `ParentComponent` to let it know which entry is getting removed:

```
updateEntry(data: any) {
    if (data) {
      if (data.action === ItemModes.Delete) {
        this.entries.splice(data.index, 1);
      } else {
        this.entries[data.index] = data.te;
      }
    }
  }
```

This is working fine as well. There is update functionality, but let's not focus on this for now.

My `trackBy` function:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index;
}
```

Now imagine I have 3 entries:

```
Entry1: { id: 1, someproperty: AAA }
Entry2: { id: 2, someproperty: BBB }
Entry3: { id: 3, someproperty: CCC }
```

I click a delete button for Entry1. `ParentComponent.updateEntry()` gets called and an index gets passed. The *correct* element gets deleted and `this.entries` is now:

```
Entry2: { id: 2, someproperty: BBB }
Entry3: { id: 3, someproperty: CCC }
```

*HOWEVER* the last entry (Entry3) is removed from UI (despite the fact that `this.entries` holds correct items). Same happens if I click delete for Entry2. But in UI it's always the last entry that gets removed. If I change the `ngfor` and remove trackBy - everything is working as expected. Can anyone please explain where am I making a mistake?

Comment: what if you use

trackByFn(index, item) {
    return item.id;
}

Comment: Just tried and is still removes the last element. `this.entries` however is correct.

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz showing the problem?